# Error in sympy.solve on Freudenstein equation

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to obtain one of the angles of Freudenstein equation (psi):

k1 * cos(psi) - k2 * cos(fi) + k3 - cos(psi - fi) = 0

I have k1, k2, k3 and fi values. I tried the following:

```
from sympy import Symbol, solve, cos

x = Symbol('x')
realPsi = solve(k1 * cos(x) - k2 * cos(fi) + k3 - cos(x - fi), x)
```

I receive this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 484, in solve solution = _solve(f, *symbols, **flags)  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 700, in _solve soln = tsolve(f_num, symbol)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1143, in tsolve "(tsolve: at least one Function expected at this point")
NotImplementedError: Unable to solve the equation(tsolve: at least one Function expected at this point
```

I don't use this kind of tools before, maybe I'm doing something really wrong...
Any idea?

Thanks,

Héctor.

EDIT:
Thanks for the fast response.

I tried the following (simple equation with cos):

```
eq = 3.2 * cos(x + 0.2).rewrite(exp) + 1.7   

eq   

Out[1]: 1.6*exp(I*(-x - 0.2)) + 1.6*exp(I*(x + 0.2)) + 1.7   

solve(1.6*exp(I*(-x - 0.2)) + 1.6*exp(I*(x + 0.2)) + 1.7, x)

NotImplementedError: Unable to solve the equation(tsolve: at least one Function expected at this point
```

Am I using correctly .rewrite??

Comment: Ah, you're just not really passing the `Equation` properly to SymPy. Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440337/solving-systems-of-equations-with-sympy?rq=1)

Comment: `NotImplementedError` means what it says - this types of equations are not solvable by sympy. The above comment is wrong, your code is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it should "just work" but here is a case where, with a little help for the "simpler equation with cos" given above you can get an answer:

```
>>> eq=3.2*cos(x+.2)+1.7
>>> [w.n(3,chop=True) for w in solve(expand(eq.rewrite(exp)))]
[-2.33, 1.93]
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I try with this solution and I also receive NotImplementedError. I don't understand this point: w.n(3,chop=True)

Comment: make sure you are using the current master. The chop=True argument eliminates small values from the evaluated expression. Without this you get

Comment: >>> [w.n(3) for w in solve(expand(eq.rewrite(exp)))]
    [-2.33 + 1.05e-140*I, 1.93 + 1.05e-140*I]

Comment: That's my problem!!When I updated sympy this solution works. Also if I use Freudenstein equation works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`NotImplementedError` means what it says, namely that a solver for this type of equations is "not implemented".

You can help SymPy a bit to find the solution:

```
>>> k * cos(x) - m * cos(y) + n - cos(x - y)
k*cos(x) - m*cos(y) + n - cos(x - y)
>>> _.rewrite(exp)
k*(exp(I*x)/2 + exp(-I*x)/2) - .....
>>> solve(_, x)
..... long solution
```

You can use `rewrite` to transform expressions written with trigonometric functions into expressions containing complex exponentials.

Comment: Your second equation does not have real solutions. I guess this is why SymPy fails. In any case, the solvers for transcendental equations are not reliable.

Comment: I misread the second equation. My comment above is wrong. See the other answer for the second equation.